# I'm trying to set up 2 virtual host on a new VPS using apache 2.x on a Ubuntu server

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

Output when trying "apache2 restart"

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                                
[Thu Feb   09 00:55:09 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost 71.19.144.240:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Feb 09 00:55:09 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:0 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Feb 09 00:55:09 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Feb 09 00:55:09 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx:80 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Feb 09 00:55:09 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:0 has no VirtualHosts
[Thu Feb 09 00:55:09 2012] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
                                                                     [fail]
```

httpd.conf file:
      GNU nano 2.2.2              File: httpd.conf

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.xxxxx.net
DocumentRoot /srv/www/xxxx.net/public_html/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *>
ServerName www.xxxxx.com
DocumentRoot /srv/www/xxxxxx.com/public_html/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
```

This means something is already running under port 80. I am guessing you are using

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

to try to restart the server. Try stopping the service first just to debug.

Again from ubuntu distribution perspective:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
```

should go under

/etc/apache2/ports.conf

and virtual host configuration options

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.xxxxx.com
DocumentRoot /srv/www/xxxxxx.com/public_html/
</VirtualHost>
```

should go under a distinct file under /etc/apache2/sites-available which is later on symlinked to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled so that apache sees if in apache's default ubuntu configuration.